# NS Record is missing, but A record is not

Tags: vagrant

I'm developing a website and i'm using the PHP function dns_get_record to get some data from the DNS server. To proper show the problem I will show an example of getting the NS record from a domain first with CentOS 7

Command: `dig php.net NS`
Result:

> ;; ANSWER SECTION: 
>   php.net.      299 IN  NS  dns4.easydns.info.
>   php.net.      299 IN  NS  dns3.easydns.org.
>   php.net.      299 IN  NS  dns2.easydns.net.
>   php.net.      299 IN  NS  dns1.easydns.com.

Also when I try to get the A record it give me proper result

But when I'm using this command on my vagrant box (Ubuntu Homestead) I don't get any NS records, there isn't an answer section...

But, when I do the same on the A record there is an answer. How can it be that a domain without any NS can resolve to an IP?

Also when I do the same on Google Dig I get the expected result

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some information on your vagrant box? How was it setup? How is its IP stack configured and the _/etc/resolv.conf_ file etc...

Comment: I took a look in /etc/resolv.conf and found it was pointing to the wrong nameserver... Thanks!

Comment: can you please post a detailed answer and mark it as accpeted, in case it helps someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the default Vagrant box with Laravel/Homestead and rebooting it I needed to change the /etc/resolv.conf - there was a wrong nameserver listed in that e. I've changed 127.0.0.53 to 8.8.8.8 and that solved it.